# Как с помощью Thymeleaf выделить слово внутри тега, удалив сам тег?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Есть ячейка в таблице, которая заполняется данными из базы

```
<td th:="${tab[0]}"></td>
```

результат строка:

```
Межрегиональная <span>комиссия</span> по борьбе с преступностью.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью Thymeleaf выделить цветом текст внутри тега span, при этом удалив сам тег?

хочу получить - Межрегиональная **комиссия** по борьбе с преступностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если строка с HTML разметкой приходит из базы данных, то её можно выделить цветом с помощью [#strings:replace](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#strings). Ваш код может выглядеть так ...

```
<td th:utext="${#strings.replace(tab[0],'<span>','<span style=color:red>')}"></td>
```

Вы не можете удалить сам тег, вместе с ним удалиться выделение цветом.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Я сейчас изучаю Спринг, и у меня возникла проблема с подключением к серверу Tomcat... Я хотел бы спросить кого-то, кто знает Спринг. Не хочу показаться наглым, но могли мы где-нибудь связаться (напр. Фейсбук)? Я просто и здесь задавал вопрос, и на англ версии, но мне мало отвечают. Буду вам очень признателен, если вы согласитесь :D